# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: php, code, xampp

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\allegiant\index.php:1 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\allegiant\index.php on line 1

I downloaded a template web free of wordpress, but i have problems with the code of this template web, when i´m going to open the file `index.html`, show me a mistake or

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()"

i has been try of give it a solution, but shows me this

> "Call to undefined function get_header() "

and i can not see or put it together. searched for em all places, but i don´t found a solution for my problem
i need help with this problem. here i will leave the code

i don´t speak your lenguage, sorry for my mistakes when i write :(

[image: problem here]

Comment: The path to the theme doesn't look right:  Have you installed WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

`get_header()` is a Wordpress template tag, so only available within Wordpress. You are using a Wordpress theme and by mistake placed it in the root folder of your site.
Place it within your WordPress installation folder in `wp-content/themes/` folder. And finally `activate` in through dashboard by navigating to Appearance -> Themes.